# Chrome does not send some ajax requests. It is still pending

Tags: google-chrome, api

I have a Vue application which do some simple requests to API endpoints. Everything worked fine  till now. Other browsers like Opera or FF works fine also Postman has no problem. Something is wrong with Chrome but I dont know what. Other PC with the same Chrome version works fine. Can somebody tell me please how to fix it or what could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you disabled all your extensions and ad blockers?

Comment: No I did not install any extension in last days.

Comment: So you thing it could be caused by some extension or application on my PC? I try to remove apps which have been installed on Friday 1.4.2022

Answer (score -2):

The problem was in the some application installed few days ago before weekend. After uninstall it works as before.

Comment: It would be worth adding what program it was to make your answer a bit more complete.